# Haskell beginner cannot match expected type

Tags: haskell, option-type, either

I need to write a program which decodes a list of four values, which can be either I or O into a list of `[Either Bool Bool]`. I know I have to use maybe, but I simply cannot wrap my head around it. Right now I am totally desperate because I simply cannot solve this problem.

An example input and output might look like this: [I,O,O,I] => [Left True, Right False]

Here is the current code I have:

```
module Blueprint where
import Prelude
import Data.Maybe

data Bit = O | I  deriving (Eq, Show)

encode :: [Either Bool Bool] -> [Bit]
encode [] = []
encode l  = case head l of
            Left  False -> [I, I] ++ encode (tail l)
            Left  True  -> [I, O] ++ encode (tail l)
            Right False -> [O, I] ++ encode (tail l)
            Right True  -> [O, O] ++ encode (tail l)

decode :: [Bit] -> Maybe [Either Bool Bool]
decode []   = Nothing
decode [x]  = Nothing
decode l = if isNothing (decode (tail (tail l)))
  then Nothing
  else case  head l of
    I -> if l!!1 == I
          then [Left False]  ++ decode (tail (tail l))
          else [Left True]  ++ decode (tail (tail l))
    O -> if l!!1 == I
          then [Right False]  ++ decode (tail (tail l))
          else [Right True] ++ decode (tail (tail l))
```

and these are the errors I get:

```
Prelude> :load serialise
[1 of 1] Compiling Blueprint        ( serialise.hs, interpreted )

serialise.hs:22:16:
    Couldn't match expected type `Maybe [Either Bool Bool]'
                with actual type `[Either Bool b0]'
    In the expression: [Left False] ++ decode (tail (tail l))
    In the expression:
      if l !! 1 == I then
          [Left False] ++ decode (tail (tail l))
      else
          [Left True] ++ decode (tail (tail l))
    In a case alternative:
        I -> if l !! 1 == I then
                 [Left False] ++ decode (tail (tail l))
             else
                 [Left True] ++ decode (tail (tail l))

serialise.hs:22:33:
    Couldn't match expected type `[Either Bool b0]'
                with actual type `Maybe [Either Bool Bool]'
    In the second argument of `(++)', namely `decode (tail (tail l))'
    In the expression: [Left False] ++ decode (tail (tail l))

serialise.hs:23:16:
    Couldn't match expected type `Maybe [Either Bool Bool]'
                with actual type `[Either Bool b1]'
    In the expression: [Left True] ++ decode (tail (tail l))
    In the expression:
      if l !! 1 == I then
          [Left False] ++ decode (tail (tail l))
      else
          [Left True] ++ decode (tail (tail l))
    In a case alternative:
        I -> if l !! 1 == I then
                 [Left False] ++ decode (tail (tail l))
             else
                 [Left True] ++ decode (tail (tail l))

serialise.hs:23:32:
    Couldn't match expected type `[Either Bool b1]'
                with actual type `Maybe [Either Bool Bool]'
    In the second argument of `(++)', namely `decode (tail (tail l))'
    In the expression: [Left True] ++ decode (tail (tail l))

serialise.hs:25:16:
    Couldn't match expected type `Maybe [Either Bool Bool]'
                with actual type `[Either a0 Bool]'
    In the expression: [Right False] ++ decode (tail (tail l))
    In the expression:
      if l !! 1 == I then
          [Right False] ++ decode (tail (tail l))
      else
          [Right True] ++ decode (tail (tail l))
    In a case alternative:
        O -> if l !! 1 == I then
                 [Right False] ++ decode (tail (tail l))
             else
                 [Right True] ++ decode (tail (tail l))

serialise.hs:25:34:
    Couldn't match expected type `[Either a0 Bool]'
                with actual type `Maybe [Either Bool Bool]'
    In the second argument of `(++)', namely `decode (tail (tail l))'
    In the expression: [Right False] ++ decode (tail (tail l))

serialise.hs:26:16:
    Couldn't match expected type `Maybe [Either Bool Bool]'
                with actual type `[Either a1 Bool]'
    In the expression: [Right True] ++ decode (tail (tail l))
    In the expression:
      if l !! 1 == I then
          [Right False] ++ decode (tail (tail l))
      else
          [Right True] ++ decode (tail (tail l))
    In a case alternative:
        O -> if l !! 1 == I then
                 [Right False] ++ decode (tail (tail l))
             else
                 [Right True] ++ decode (tail (tail l))

serialise.hs:26:32:
    Couldn't match expected type `[Either a1 Bool]'
                with actual type `Maybe [Either Bool Bool]'
    In the second argument of `(++)', namely `decode (tail (tail l))'
    In the expression: [Right True] ++ decode (tail (tail l))
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Right now **anything** that helps me solve this problem is welcome. I have tried this for the better part of the day and I simply can't solve it.

Answer (score 5):

You need to put a `Just` before your `case` statement to convert those values to `Maybe [Either Bool Bool]` instead of just `[Either Bool Bool]`:

```
decode :: [Bit] -> Maybe [Either Bool Bool]
decode []   = Nothing
decode [x]  = Nothing
decode l = if isNothing (decode (tail (tail l)))
  then Nothing
  else Just $ case head l of
    I -> if l!!1 == I
          then [Left False]  ++ decode (tail (tail l))
          else [Left True]  ++ decode (tail (tail l))
    O -> if l!!1 == I
          then [Right False]  ++ decode (tail (tail l))
          else [Right True] ++ decode (tail (tail l))
```

But this won't solve all of it.  You also have `decode` embedded in that computation, and its type is `Maybe [Either Bool Bool]`, but to use `++` you need just the `[Either Bool Bool]` as `++` only works with lists.  This is where the `Maybe` monad comes in handy:

```
decode [] = Nothing
decode [x] = Nothing
decode (x:y:rest) = do
    end <- decode rest
    let this = case (x, y) of
            (I, I) -> Left False
            (I, O) -> Left True
            (O, I) -> Right False
            (O, O) -> Right True
    return (this : end)
```

The case statement here is really just a different way of writing your case/nested-ifs.  I also used pattern matching to avoid all the uses of `head`, `!!`, and `tail` since those functions should usually be avoided (they call `error` instead of doing proper error handling using `Maybe`).  The `<-` syntax for `Maybe` will exit the computation early if `Nothing` is returned, so `end <- decode rest` is the same as saying `if isNothing (decode rest) then Nothing else <continue>`.  Then, instead of building the entire result in each branch of the case/ifs, just compute the single result from `x` and `y`, then build the result list at the end.

Comment: Also note that the new version is only using total methods making it safer. Pattern matching `x/y` avoids having to decide whether `head` or `!!1` is safe to do later. Even though it is safe after analysis, it is nice to avoid the analysis.

Comment: @Ruhrpottpatriot: Understanding the `Maybe` monad requires understanding monads. In this case the transformation is simple, you can remove the `return`/`do` and replace `end <- decode rest` with the snippet he provided and you will have identical execution. I always think of the `Maybe` monad as "if `<-` return `Nothing` you end up with `Nothing` and `return` is a synonym for `Just`"

Comment: @Ruhrpottpatriot the `Maybe` type is defined as `data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a`.  There isn't anything special to it really, the type just has two constructors: `Nothing :: Maybe a` and `Just :: a -> Maybe a`.  In order to construct a value of type `Maybe a`, you use one of these two constructors.  Applying `Just` to a value of type `a` constructs a new value of type `Maybe a`, and using `Nothing` just constructs a value of type `Maybe a`, no inputs needed.

Comment: Even though I deleted my comment accidentally. Thanks for the infos on `Maybe`

Comment: @Ruhrpottpatriot If you haven't seen it yet I would recommend reading through [Learn You a Haskell](http://www.learnyouahaskell.com/chapters), it covers `Maybe` and a lot of other concepts in more depth, and eventually monads, functors, and the like.

Comment: @bheklilr No I haven't seen it yet. Thanks for the tip! However: If I take your solution and try it, I simply get `Nothing` when I type in [I,O,O,I] ...strange.

Comment: I might also add, that I run ghci with -Wall and -Werror and thus had to replace the `decode [x] = Nothing` with `decode [ _ ] = Nothing` If I understood my tutorials correctly, this can be done, right?

Comment: @Ruhrpottpatriot Yes, that's perfectly all right.  The difference between `[x]` and `[_]` in a pattern is that they both match a list with 1 element, in the first one the value of that element is assigned to the name `x` and in the second one the value of that element isn't assigned to anything, the `_` is only there to force the pattern to match a list with one element.  It could be said that `_` is used for matching structures only, not the data itself.  For example `[_, _, _]` would match a 3 element list, but `[x, y, z]` would match the only 3 elements of a list with `x`, `y`, and `z`.

Comment: Ok. That I got right at least :) But why is the program spewing out nothing for each possible combination. It does not matter why I type in, I always get nothing.

Comment: @Ruhrpottpatriot As for the problem with `[I, O, O, I]` returning `Nothing`, that's because it decodes the `I` and `O`, then the `O` and `I`, then `[]`, which returns `Nothing`.  This is actually a mistake on my part (that's what I get for not running the code first =P), but I think you can turn it into a good exercise.  Consider matching the patterns `[]`, `[_]`, `[x, y]`, and then `(x:y:rest)`.  Does this give you any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: @bheklilr Since if one part of the equation is evalued to `Nothing` the rest is also nothing, my first thought would be to replace the `decode [] = Nothing` with `decode [] = []` and `decode [_] = Nothing` with `decode [_] = Just []`. That ensures we don't get a `Nothing` back, but rather en empty list which we can concat, since swapping the order of evaluations does not work. However now the result is something along `Just [Left False,Right False]` and I think I have an error of thought somewhere in that.

Comment: @Ruhrpottpatriot your reasoning is sound (although it should be `decode [] = Just []`, so maybe you just have a typo in your code or test input somewhere?

Comment: @bheklilr It's a typo on SO. My source has `decode [] = Just []`